# how to change where summernote looks for images

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, summernote

Everything works for me on summernote but when i add image in the text it dosent show up in frontend i know the reason is that it looks for image on `localhost:3000/media/django-summernote/2021-12-06/default.png` but istead of 3000 it should be going to `localhost:8000`

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    path('api/', include('api.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

] + static (settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


urlpatterns +=[re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
```

admin.py

```
from .models import BlogPost

class BlogPostAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('slug',)
    list_display = ('id', 'title', 'category', 'date_created')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'title')
    search_fields = ('title',)
    list_per_page = 25
    summernote_fields = ('content',)

admin.site.register(BlogPost, BlogPostAdmin)
```

Comment: Show me your summernote code..

Comment: @TariqAhmed what exactly u want me to show (i added admin.py)

Comment: By default summernote use base64 maybe for pictures..

Comment: so what  should i do to get the images?